# Слово "улица" в написании и произношении проспектов, бульваров и шоссе

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня с руководителем возник спор.
В разговоре я сказала "улица Комсомольский проспект, дом №...", на что получила объяснение: *"Комсомольский—это проспект, а не улица, так же как и Копейское шоссе—это шоссе, а не улица, Южный бульвар—это бульвар, а не улица".*
И тогда(с горечью на душе за то, что мне утерли нос), понимая, что и шоссе, и бульвар, и проспект—это разновидности улиц, я стала размышлять:
***могу ли я говорить и писать "ул. Копейское шоссе; ул. Южный бульвар; ул.Комсомольский проспект"***(т.к. шоссе, бульвар, проспект идут вторым словом, следовательно, это названия улиц)?
шоссе Металлургов или ш. Металлургов—это уже действительно шоссе; проспект Победы, бульвар Славы—это действительно проспект и бульвар(так как разновидность улицы упоминается первым словом); ***будет ли уместно говорить "ул. проспект Победы"?***
Пожалуйста, ответьте, уж очень хочется разрешить этот спор.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Если верить Википедии, в Перми есть улица Комсомольский проспект. В этом случае Комсольский проспект становится именем собственном. Улица - родовым словом.

Comment: Нет в Перми такой улицы https://www.google.ru/maps/@58.0039978,56.2465289,16.75z  Есть **Комсомольский проспект**

Comment: В Википедеи написано, что это название улицы. У проспекта не может быть нумерации, а в интернете встречается с нумерацией.

Answer (score 6):

Улица, проспект, аллея, шоссе, бульвар, тупик, переулок, площадь  — это родовые территориальные названия одного порядка, поэтому правильно: **Южный бульвар, проспект Победы, Копейское шоссе.**

Но: улица **Борисовские Пруды**, так как "пруды" не являются родовым словом в административных названиях, связанных с территориальной адресацией.

[Названия государств, административно-территориальных единиц, станций и т. д. | Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18)

Comment: *"пруды" не являются родовым словом в административных названиях, связанных с территориальной адресацией.* - это бы конечно многое объясняло, но где об этом написано четко и ясно? Какие еще слова "не являются"? Театр, например? Спуск? "7-я (л/Л)иния В,О."? Или "Линия" тоже "не является"?

Comment: @Мимоходов Категории: Улицы Василеостровского района. Линии Санкт-Петербурга(линии все-таки): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0 и https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) - линии - с маленькой буквы - всегда и сейчас.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я не совсем понял, вы ответ на мой вопрос Sibylla знаете?  Где написано что "линия" не является  родовым словом? Я еще могу согласиться с театром, но Линия?! А адресный справочник я и без вас найду.  И вез Вики.

Comment: Нет, ответа - однозначного - я, конечно, не знаю. Но! - тридцать лет назад я некоторое время жила в Ленинграде, и всегда удивлялась: почему "линии"  - "мелкие" - с маленькой буквы? Так что, наоборот,  я Вас поддерживаю. Василеостровские Линии - это больше, чем просто улицы.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова не надо меня поддерживать в том, что не является прямым предметом спора. Предмет же этот (да и то уж как ответвление от отсновного спора) касается только трактовки правила Розенталя, а не статуса линий как таковых. И моя проблема, похожее, близка к разрешению. Если перед сочетанияем нет слова "улица" то линия и не подпадает под  розенталевское правило (если его правильно трактовать). А все опрошенные мной питерцы единогласно заявили, что слово "улица" перед номером линии - ошибка. Вопрос о заглавной в этом случае я выношу за скобки.

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Причина - в комментариях. Автор не понял вопроса. А он глубже упоминания "родового слова."

Answer (score 3):

Ксения, в разговоре "улица бульвар такой-то" совершенно неуместно. Ни "улица шоссе", ни "улица переулок", ни что-то еще подобное невозможно, ибо после слова "улица" должно следовать название, а слово, означающее тип улицы, в название не входит. Ваше употребление некорректно.

Но на письме такое может иногда возникать в силу того, что "улицами" за неимением более подходящего слова стали называть любой транспортный (а подчас — даже пешеходный) элемент адресной инфраструктуры населенного пункта, вплоть до площадей. Чтобы подчеркнуть, что это не улица в узком смысле, приходится к названию добавлять слово проспект, площадь, шоссе...
Вот и появляется такая "улица Комсомольский проспект". Но это нежелательная ситуация, допустимая разве только в профессиональной речи проектировщиков или почтальонов.

Есть, правда, некоторые исключения. Скажем, ***"улица Андреевский спуск"*** (Киев), ***"улица Зеленский спуск"*** (Н. Новгород — наряду с рядом идущим  просто "Зеленским спуском", который не улица — поди разберись...), ***"улица Почаинский овраг"*** (там же), ***"Улица Сивцев вражек"*** (Москва) или ***"улица Владимирский тракт"*** (ныне в черте Москвы переименована, но осталась в городах областного значения). Спуск, тракт и даже овраг (=вражек) — это ведь исторические названия "типов улиц", но при этом они в современном восприятии слились с именем собсвенным, став единым топонимом. Не буду сейчас искать, помнится, подобные названия есть и в других городах.

Совсем уж причудливый пример — "Площадь Васильевский спуск" (Москва). Это название узаконено, хотя площадь по своей сути никогда не может быть "спуском". Да и сейчас ничего там нет от пощади, кроме некоторой "площадной" широты. В результате рождаются монстры типа ***"Улица Площадь Васильевский спуск"***. Ну тут уже без комментариев.

В общем, коли возникла такая полемика, я попробую разобраться по существу.
Совершенно не согласен с утверждением об очевидности понимания розенталевского правила.

============

В общем так. 
Я уже почти убедил было себя, что родовое слово в формулировке Розенталя - это ***само слово "улица"*** (или сопоставимые с ним "площадь" "переулок", "шоссе", "проспект" и прочее) **вне** имени собственного (а не внутри него, как следует из прямого понимания Розенталя). Тогда бы выходило, что ***Зеленский спуск*** - со строчной (спуск - родовое слово), ***Улица Зеленский Спуск*** - со строчной ("Спуск" - часть названия, не родовое слово). При этом ***Проезд Художественного театра*** - просто другая форма, "театр" не входит в имя собственное и поэтому остаётся родовым словом. "Улица Зеленского спуска", существуй она в топонимики Нижнего, тоже писалась бы со строчной (примеры постараюсь найти).

Но повсеместное использование названий типа "улица ***7-я линия*** В.О." переворачивает всю логику, по которой она писалась бы со строчной.
Остается только предположить, что исходная форма - Улица ***7-й линии В.О.***

По-другому объяснить не могу. Спрошу знатоков питерской топонимики, если подтвердят, я для себя этот вопрос закрою. Но это на основном ответе скажется минимально или никак.

Comment: Обсуждение [продолжается в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60669/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 2):

```
     шоссе, и бульвар, и проспект—это разновидности улиц
```

Вот именно, проспект - разновидность улицы. Улицы бывают всякие - просто улицы, стандартные, и разные другие типы. Когда мы говорим "улица",  мы имеем в виду  стандартную улицу(не переулок и не аллею),а говорим "проспект", мы видим не обычную улицу, а прямую, длинную и широкую,  если "шоссе",то это улица,направленная на выезд из города, если "бульвар"- широкая улица со скамейками, газонами и аллеями для пешеходов, поэтому Вас и поправили: улица и проспект не одно и то же.Это всё официальные названия, нужно их различать. Вот если мы говорим "бахчи", мы же имеем в виду дыни и арбузы, а не кабачки?А кабачки - тоже бахчи, так что разновидность чего-то следует называть сразу без указания на общее значение, если не собираетесь их все перечислять. (В этом городе мы видим улицы разного типа: и маленькие улочки, и большие проспекты, и зелёные аллеи...)

Answer (score 2):

Все эти коллизии часто связаны с компьютерными базами данных. Если адрес задаётся несколькими полями (город, улица, дом и т.д.) и если в поле "Улица" мы напишем "Ольховая", то в распечатанном виде все будет нормально. А если наша улица называется Комсомольский проспект – здесь-то и начнется самое интересное.
Не печатать слово "улица"? Тогда рядом можем увидеть: "Ольховая, 15" и "Комсомольский пр., 150". Тоже не есть хорошо.

Но в принципе, если отвлечься от всех этих компьютеров, то монстр "улица Комсомольский проспект" не имеет права на существование.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос правильного написания адреса и, тем более, с сокращениями трогает многих.

Здесь http://www.doless.ru/kak-pravilno-sokrashhat-adresa.html приведены примеры общепринятых сокращений:
улица       ул.   (у.) 
проспект    пр-т  (просп., пр-кт) 
проезд      пр-д  (пр.) 
переулок    пер.  (переул.) 
площадь     пл.   (площ.) 
бульвар     б-р   (бул., бульв.) 
набережная  наб.  (набережн., набереж.) 
шоссе       ш.    (шос.) 
тупик       туп. 
аллея       ал.   (алл.)

Делаем вывод, что  *проспект* называть еще и  *улицей* не принято. Это ненужная тавтология.

Answer (score 0):

Проспект является широкой проезжей улицей, предназначенной для движения транспорта. Так, как правило, называют главные улицы или те, которые при наличии маршрутов городского общественного транспорта соединяют важные улицы, площади или части города. В российских же СНИП *проспект* не является типом улицы, хотя на практике в условиях исторически сложившейся среды такая классификация часто отвергается и пересматривается.

Бульвар представляет собой аллею с обязательной пешеходной зоной и зелёными насаждениями. *Бульвары* могут находиться в любой части города, часто являясь зелёной отдушиной в промзонах или возле загруженных дорог. Но в стихийно складывающейся застройке догм не бывает, и чередующиеся бульвары так и улицы Садового кольца одинаково обходятся без таких отдушин.

В полном смысле не являются улицами по определению — *шоссе, переулки, проезды, тупики, набережные и площади*, и они представлены в названиях городских дорог как неотъемлемый элемент (родовое имя) наряду с уже упомянутыми.

Слово *улица* перед «адресной строкой» — лишнее, оно уместно только в табличных формах для заполнения тогда, когда нет обобщённого окна *Адрес*.

Comment: Если верить Википедии (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), шоссе, переулки, проезды, тупики, набережные - это типы улиц. Если в вашем распоряжении есть более достоверный источник, было бы хорошо на него сослаться.

Comment: Я имел в виду именно «по определению» или в строгом понимании улицы как части общей сети сообщений внутри города.